# C# Web App thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading

i'm in trouble. In my web app i have a code that creates a thread on the Click event of a button to perform a data intensive task, the is like this:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Show loader image
    loader.Show();

    // Creating the thread
    System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart ts = new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(RunThread);
    Thread t = new Thread(ts);
    t.Name = "BackgroundThread";
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
    t.Start(HttpContext.Current);
}
private void RunThread(object state)
{
    // Setting the current thread property as the background thread
    CurrentThread = Thread.CurrentThread;

    if (IsThreadRunning(CurrentThread))
    {
        CurrentThread.Join(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(6d));
    }

    // DO SOME HEAVY STUFF
}
```

In the button click i show the loader. The problem is: Even calling **Join** in the **BackgroundThread**, the Page_Load event gets called frequently making the page refresh. In other words, while the **RunThread** doesn´t finish, the Page_Load is getting called. Could i prevent this from happening?

**OBS: What i wanna do is: show the loader while the data intensive thread is running without make repetitive refreshs on the page.**

Comment: Don't call high priority threads fro `page_load`? If you explain what problem this is trying to solve, perhaps a better option can be offered.

Comment: Please make your question more clear, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you calling `Join` on the current thread? That's a meaningless operation.

Comment: @Anri I've update my post to give you a better explanation.

Comment: You're going about this all wrong. You need to have a separate channel entirely that handles the data intensive task, and you need to ask that object about the state of the running code. As it is, the computer is doing just what you've asked it to.

Comment: Also, there's almost no use of Threads directly that can't be done better (faster, more efficiently, with less overhead) using Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to check long running task status from web page without polling (making postback from time to time) is to use Web Sockets, but i'm pretty sure using it would be big overhead for this kind of tasks.

I would use ajax requests to prevent full page reload.

Seems like you need to read more about the whole web request and response process.

Comment: Simply put, i want to forbid the page to get served to the client before my long running task ends. It would be like a Join on the long running thread. But even when i call join, the page follows his normal cycle and gets served to the client.

Comment: Can't you do the job on the main thread? You may also run into timeout.

Comment: Some strange thing happened! When i deployed the webapp on to the staging server of my company, the problem aforementioned(frequent refresh) faded out. Seems that it only happened because the app was running in debug mode.